# Ubuntu freezes sometimes

Tags: 20.04

I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows in my Laptop. But Ubuntu freezes after 20-50 minutes works. I've made a probe: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=2bdba73cfa
I will be really appreciated if someone help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much RAM does the laptop have? And how do you use it?

Comment: 4GB, it uses only for browser and internal Ubuntu process

Comment: If you open too many tabs in a browser, the system can start swapping and freeze.

Comment: I just only open 4 tab. I think I have another problem. When I use windows, I can open more than 40 tabs and do not have a problem at all

Comment: *I can open more than 40 tabs and do not have a problem at all* with a Pentium N4200 (or Celeron N3350?)and 2*2GB DDR3 RAM? No, not happening, but we can chalk this up to hyperbole. Is Ubuntu installed in the same internal drive? And, of course, updating UEFI is strongly recommended.

Comment: Ubuntu uses the same internal drive. The problem is not related to surfing the Internet. This happens when I don't even open the browser

Comment: perhaps someone gives me another piece of advice? Because the issue didn't solve